Jetpack Compose: Preserve Layout Direction in Multi-Language Support
I want to preserve layout direction in multi-language support. Because some contents always have a default direction. For example, a Username or Password TextField. No matter what the Android system language setup either Arabic or English, the Username and Password Normally have English letters and are filled LTR in a LTR layout direction.
Once again, I want to keep the layout direction in multi-language support for some content.
How to achieve that?

in order make some composables layout always LFT you can use this function:
@Composable
fun LeftToRightLayout(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) 
    {
        content()
    }
  }

example of usage:
 @Composable
fun MyTextFiled(){
   LeftToRightLayout { 
      TextField()
  } 
}

so you like that force the MyTextFiled composable to be always ltr even if the whole app is wrapped with rtl
